# AntD using Form [form]=Form.useForm() is not a function or is not iterable React

Tags: reactjs, antd

Im tring to build a table with and editable cell but when reading documentation and using

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```

It breaks. I've tried it all

Comment: Hi @diego3799 and welcome to SO.  Can you tell us more specifically what you've tried, give us a whole code example, and tell us what the error is, specifically?  See this guide if you need an example of what I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
"dependencies": {
        "antd": "^4.0.0",
}
```

Update your antd npm package version to 4.0.0. This method / function is not supported in lower versions of antd.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use a tool to migrate V3 to V4. Instead of Form from `antd`, it's using Form from `@ant-design/compatible` dependency.

> import { Form } from '@ant-design/compatible';

So, in order to use new API of Form, let's import directly from `antd`

> import { Form } from 'antd';

Comment: but we can get `Error: Attempted to call useForm() from the server but useForm is on the client`

Answer (score 0):

use Form.create() instead if your antd is 3.x.x version